How do I remove the step values from a function in Pytest-allure?
I don't want the params from a def with the anotation @allure.step() to be shown on the allure report.
For example:
@allure.step("Logging in...")
def validate_user(self, user, password):
  login(user, password)


It's showing the params user and password and their values on the report generated by allure.
Is it possible to hide them?
Bassically, the report should have the "Logging in..." step without the params
